# Speedtest-cli python script, inserting sql with wrong values

Tags: python, cron, mysql-python, mysql-connector

Relatively new to python scripts, so bare with.

I have used speedtest-cli before. I have edited the script so it will insert the values into a sql table as below, however having an issue with one of the inserts. It will insert ping, and download ok, however, the upload is always 2.74 or 2.75 for example, but ONLY when run from a crontab.. very weird.

If I run the python script from cli it will insert values fine.
This is my query, and the values ping, download and upload are coming from the speedtest-cli script.

Here is the full script

```
import re

import subprocess

import time

import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from mysql.connector import errorcode


print "----------------------------------"
print 'Started: {} {}'.format(time.strftime('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S'), "")

response = subprocess.Popen('speedtest-cli --simple', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()



ping = re.findall('Ping:\s(.*?)\s', response, re.MULTILINE)

download = re.findall('Download:\s(.*?)\s', response, re.MULTILINE)

upload = re.findall('Upload:\s(.*?)\s', response, re.MULTILINE)



ping[0] = ping[0].replace(',', '.')

download[0] = download[0].replace(',', '.')

upload[0] = upload[0].replace(',', '.')



try:

    if os.stat('/var/www/html/speed/log.txt').st_size == 0:

        print 'Date,Time,Ping (ms),Download (Mbit/s),Upload (Mbit/s)'

except:

    pass



print 'PING: {}, DOWN: {}, UP: {}'.format(ping[0], download[0], upload[0])



try:
   connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                             database='dev',
                             user='dev',
                             password='dev1')

   sql_insert_query = ("""INSERT INTO speedtest(ping, download, upload) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)""", (ping[0], download[0], upload[0]))

   cursor = connection.cursor()
   result  = cursor.execute(*sql_insert_query)
   connection.commit()
   print ("Insert success into speedtest tbl")

except mysql.connector.Error as error :
    connection.rollback() #rollback if any exception occured
    print("Failed inserting record into speedtest table {}".format(error))

finally:
    #closing database connection.
    if(connection.is_connected()):
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("MySQL conn closed")


print 'Finished: {} {}'.format(time.strftime('%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S'), "")
```

Manual script runs ok, just from crontab I get unexpected values. Not sure how to solve.

Comment: Cron doesn't run your script in the same environment as you get in a terminal window or a bash shell. So it's likely failing trying to find some file. You can't use files named `~/foobar` you have to use `/home/someuser/foobar` or cron can't find the file. You've not supplied the whole script and you've not logged anything from cron. So it's impossible to tell you what's gone wrong.

Comment: Hi Dougie, 
I have edited the post with the full python script. I dont understand, if it is missing a file, while it will insert the ping, download but not the upload, and for this we get a 'randomised' within a range, value.